# PHP preg_match_all html

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

how can i create a preg_match_all regex pattern for php to give me this code?

```
<td class="class2">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="class2" align="right"><span class="DarkText">I WANT THIS TEXT</span></td>
```

To get me the text inside the span class?
thanks!

Comment: Is this the only span class in the the text string?

Comment: xpath is much better suited to this task.

Comment: Please don't use regexes to parse HTML.  It is a path to sorrow and broken code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
preg_match_all("!<span[^>]+>(.*?)</span>!", $str, $matches);
```

Then your text will be inside the first capture group (as seen on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/98yGJR4x3J))

With that out of the way, note that [regex shouldn't be used to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You will be better off using an XML parser, unless it's something really, really simple.

Comment: +1 for answer and pointing to best solution (parser). And for including the link to Bobince's famous answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also not use `!` at start and end, and use much simpler code with [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com)

```
$pattern = "<span[^>]+>(.*?)</span>"; // no delimiters :)

$string = '
<td class="class2">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="class2" align="right"><span class="DarkText">I WANT THIS 
TEXT</span></td>
';
```

Then just use `match()->group()`:

```
$text = Pattern::of($pattern)->match($string)->group(1)->first();

$text // 'I WANT THIS TEXT'
```

Check it online: https://regex101.com/r/nxTvS1/1