# PHP Getting text/value from a span by id and put it in a variable from an external site with cURL

Tags: php, variables, html, between

My question is, how do I get the value/text by id, thats between a span from an external website by using cURL. And after that, put it in a variable.

I have the following span:

```
<span id="company" class="company">Example</span>
```

I tried to use:

```
$company = $_POST['company'];
echo($company);
```

But that didn't work.

The output should be:

```
Example
```

Answer (score 1):

To work with `$_POST` data, you actually have to post the content, typically in a form. The only way to do what you want is to fetch and extract the data from the HTML file itself. ([`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) and [`curl`](http://php.net/curl) may come in handy at this point)

Finally, you're going to have to parse and extract the data from your obtained content. There are a handful of ways you could do this including using a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722770/php-preg-match-all-html) or by working directly with the [Document Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code) (DOM). (I prefer the latter method.)

Comment: Hi Louis, thanks for your reply. Yes I am using curl. I want to get the text/value from a span that's on an external website.

Comment: So `curl` the page's content, and parse out the data by working with the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `POST` data I'm assuming you're submitting a form on the page already.

Part of your page probably looks like this:

```
<span id="company" class="company"><?php echo $company; ?></span>
```

Just add this to your form:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" />

    ...
</form>
```

Now when you submit the form `$_POST['company']` will be populated.

Comment: Hi Carson, thanks for your reply. I am using curl, sorry for not mentioning it. The span is from an external website.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see that. In that case go with Louis' answer - and take his advice and use a DOM parser, don't use regular expressions (see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/84478)